# Steam opens Civ V in a window instead of in full screen (Ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: gnome, games, steam

I have had Steam installed for years on Ubuntu, all to play a single game: Civilization V. I never had a problem with it until recently.

Normally, when starting the game it runs in full screen mode. Recently, I started it up and it opened in a window. The window is a bit strange -- the program *seems* to be running in full screen, but with a window in front that only let's me see a part of the screen (like a negative mask). When I right-click the title bar, a popup menu appears and gives me the option to minimize or close the window, but the maximize option is dimmed as if the window is already maximized.

This issue seems to have come about when I upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10, but it had been awhile since I played so I cannot say for sure. It was also shortly after I had plugged in an external monitor for the first time (I'm running this on a laptop), though I get the same result whether I run Civ V with or without the external monitor.

What I have done to try to fix it:

- Use `-full` or `-fullscreen` launch options -- no effect.
- Reinstall Steam -- no effect.
- Reinstall Civ V -- no effect.
- Reinstall gnome-shell -- no effect.

I have also inspected every Steam and Civ V config file I can find to see if there are any options there, but with no luck.

Since the window only shows part of the screen, the game is now unplayable. Any ideas about how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution proposed by @sigi714 did not *completely* work for me, but it got me far enough along to finish a solution that did. Ultimately, my `/home/USER/.local/share/Aspyr` did not include any JSON files whatsoever, so I simply made the suggested edits to `FSResID`, `WindowResX`, and `WindowResY` in `GraphicsSettingsDX9.ini` -- the X and Y values, were set quite low and I changed them to match my own 1920x1080 screen resolution.

Starting Civ V with these changes, it still started as described above -- seemingly in full-screen mode, but with a window acting as sort of a mask so I could only see part of the game. The window size did not respect the new resolution settings, but it *was* larger, and larger enough so that I could actually get into the game settings and see them. Despite the resolution being set to 1920x1080 in the `GraphicsSettingsDX9.ini` file, it was shown as 1400x900 from inside the game. I changed it to 1920x1080, ensured the full-screen box was ticked, saved the changes, and quit the game. Upon restart, it worked in full screen as it always had before.

Checking the `GraphicsSettingsDX9.ini` settings, I see that I now have:

```
FSResID = 14
WindowResX = 1920
WindowResY = 1080
```

I also now have `com.aspyr.civ5xp.json` in my `Aspyr` folder with `DisplayFullScreen` set to `true`.

Knowing a little better what to look for now, thanks to @sigi714, I found couple of places (such as the [Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Steam/Games_troubleshooting)) that indicate the correct value of `FSResID` is system-dependent, which would explain why the game chose a different value for me than for @sigi714.

Answer (score 2):

Changing this completely to a more dirty solution:

1. Go to `/home/USER/.local/share/Aspyr`
2. Make sure `com.aspyr.civ5xp.json` has:
   `"DisplayFullScreen" : true`
3. Go to subfolder “Sid Meier's Civilization 5”
4. Edit `GraphicsSettingsDX9.ini` for:

```
FSResID = 6
WindowResX = 1920
WindowResY = 1080
```

Comment: Answer doesn't fix the issue.
Also fix your typos please.

Comment: workround  -> workaround

Comment: Switch moitor --> Switch monitor

Comment: the question is how to get back to fullscreen, the answer should not be stay in windowed mode ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Changed the solution completely. You may have to play with the numbers. In case something goes wrong, game will create a new .ini, not sure about the .json, so keep a backup.

Comment: Thanks -- this did not _completely_ solve the issue for me, but it got me far enough along that I was able to figure out the rest. I will edit my question to detail the solution that worked for me.